# Selecting triples from an RDF graph where subject is in list1 or object is in list2 using Sparql in rdflib

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

Let G be an RDF graph and list1 and list2 be tow lists of URIs. I want to select all triples where ?subject ?p ?object such that ?subject is in list1 or ?object is in list2 using Sparql. I implemented the following code in rdflib but it does not work:

```
list1_uris = ", ".join(f"{uri}" for uri in list1)
list2_uris = ", ".join(f"{uri}" for uri in list2)

myquery = """
SELECT *
WHERE {
  {
    ?subject ?p ?object .
    FILTER (?subject IN (list1_uris))
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?subject ?p ?object .
    FILTER (?object IN (list2_uris))
  }
}
"""

qres = G.query(myquery)
```

It seems this code in FILTER clause is not a right one for rdflib. Do any ones know what is the true syntax in this library?

This is a real example:

```
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("testExample2.ttl")

list1 = ["http://www.semanticweb.org/amhsn/ontologies/2023/5/untitled-ontology-3#Water", "http://www.semanticweb.org/amhsn/ontologies/2023/5/untitled-ontology-3#cow_meat"]
list2 = ["http://www.semanticweb.org/amhsn/ontologies/2023/5/untitled-ontology-3#cow_meat", "http://www.semanticweb.org/owl/owlapi/turtle#Ali"]

list1_uris = ", ".join(f"{uri}" for uri in list1)
list2_uris = ", ".join(f"{uri}" for uri in list2)

print(list1_uris)

myquery = """
SELECT *
WHERE {
  {
    ?subject ?p ?object .
    FILTER (?subject IN (list1_uris))
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?subject ?p ?object .
    FILTER (?object IN (list2_uris))
  }
}
"""

qres = g.query(myquery)

for row in qres:
    print(row)
```

and the error is as following image:
[image: the result of query]

Comment: "does not work" can be for many reason - best if you also show a small sample of data and what happens when you execute your code.

At a minimum the syntax needs to be correct - `FILTER (  X in (A, B, C) )` so list1_uris and list2_uris don't look right. 

It is a good idea to print the actual query string so you can check it has been formed correctly.

Comment: #AndyS I made some changes to get what you mentioned about  what should be in filter clause. But I yet face with some errors. I will put a small sample as well.

Comment: What are the errors? I'd guess a syntax error because it'll `{list1_uris}` and make `myquery = f""""` or another way inPython to substitute variables. This is why I suggest printing the string just before executing it so you n check it is what you expect.

Comment: this is Python code, you obviously have to apply String interpolation to make the query work. I mean, so far all you have is a multi-line string - nothing more, nothing less. As @AndyS mentioned, you also have to make it e.g. an f-String and use curly brackets for the variables wrapper - this indeed would need to escape all other curly brackets of the SPARQL query itself, otherwise Python would think they wrap another variable. Or you just use `.format` with the appropriate syntax. Did you have a look at Python string interpolation at all? There are simple guides online